# Comparing the string data in the array and in the Realm database?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, realm

I need to compare the string data in the array and in the Realm database. There is this array in the code:

```
let months_arr = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
```

There is a created Realm database with the elements:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import UIKit

class EventsDB: Object {
@objc  dynamic var dataMonth = ""
@objc  dynamic var dataDay = ""
@objc  dynamic var desc = ""
@objc  dynamic var link = ""

}
```

(in the database is already written in the column dataMonth, the value "April")

It is necessary to compare the string values ​​"April" in months_arr and "April" in dataMonth.

I understand that to extract data from the database I will have to do something like this:

```
let dat = realm.objects(EventsDB)
let filter = dat.filter("dataMonth")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch an `EventsDB` object from your Realm whose `dataMonth` property is set to a certain month, you can use below piece of code:

```
let month = "April"
let events = realm.objects(EventsDB.self)
let eventsInApril = events.filter("dataMonth == %@",month)
```